Read custom HTTP headers sent from Java Spring Boot using Angular, got null
I use Angular to read http header from Java Spring Boot,
It works fine in Postman. I can read all the headers.
But when I use Angular, I got status 200, but null for headers.
Please help.  Where did i go wrong?
this is my java spring api
my rest api:
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public ResponseEntity<String> welcome(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization","test token");
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .headers(headers)
                .build();
    }

my spring security setup for all headers:
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
                            @Override
                            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                                
                                CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                                config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                                config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                                config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                                config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                                config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                                return config;
                            }
                        }))
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/welcome","/","/login","/register").permitAll()
//                        .requestMatchers("/products").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.disable())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        
        return http.build();
    }

this is my angular http request
my http service setup:
  getWelcome$(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url_welcome, {
      observe: 'response',
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }

my component function:
  onGetWelcome() {
    this.httpService.getWelcome$().subscribe({
      next: (res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        this.authHeader = res.headers.get('Authorization') as string;
        console.log(res.status);
        console.log(this.authHeader);
      },
      error: (error) => console.log(error),
      complete: () => console.log('completed.'),
    });
  }

I've changed HttpResponse < any >  to HttpReponse < string > , doesn't work.
When I tried to read the headers from other website like {JSON} Placeholder,
my angular can read certain header like "Content-Type".
So I guess it's my Java ResponseEntity went wrong.
I changed Java ResponseEntity, headers.set, headers.add, different approach that I can get from web. No luck.
Any idea?

I found the solution, mentioned in this post.
in the backend, as I add my custom header, I need to add one more header:
headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","*");

and angular can read all the custom headers!
